# AWS - how to disable "view/change user data"?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

AWS management console has a new feature to view the content of the user data.
In EC2 under "Actions->Instance Settings->View/Change User Data", it displays the user data provided as one of the parameters during VM creation API ec2_conn.run_instances.

Is there an option in python API ec2_conn.run_instances to disable this?

The use case for this:
Customer launches a commercial AMI image, and the AMI publishing company does not want the customer to view the secret user-data.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If it's "secret" it shouldn't be in the instance metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Data is retrieved via the `DescribeInstanceAttribute` API call.

Permissions [**can** be denied](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_EvaluationLogic.html) for calling this API function, but **cannot be restricted** based upon the specific AMI that was used. Nor can permission be denied by the maker of the AMI. So, it's an "all or nothing" decision.

An alternative would be to **encrypt the data being passed**, adding code to the AMI so that it is able to decrypt the data. If a user views the User Data, the sensitive portion would then be unintelligible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried to vote "UP" but I couldn't because I need 15 reputation to vote.

Comment: How can we deny the permission to call this DescribeInstanceAttribute API call?  Which boto python API we can use to do so?  Could you provide an example.  Thanks a lot...

Comment: As the Asker, you can Accept the answer instead of doing an Upvote.

Comment: Instead of Denying the API call, you could simply not grant it. All permissions are a default of "Deny", and then IAM is used to grant permissions. However, you could also explicitly Deny permissions. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_EvaluationLogic.html